# Ruby method to cycle array to the right

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a ruby method that will cycle every element in an array to the right by a specific number? 
For example, if it takes in the array [1,2,3,4] and the shift number 1, returns [4,1,2,3]. 
Or if it takes in the array [1,2,3,4,5] and the shift number 2, returns [4,5,1,2,3]. 
I could make the method myself, but ruby usually already has a method for this type of thing. I'm having trouble finding it since I don't know what it would be called. The array methods `cycle` and `shift` do not have this behavior.

Comment: If you looked through `Array` methods before asking the question weren't you curious about the one called "rotate"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`rotate`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-rotate) method which does similar things

```
2.6.5 :012 > arr = [1,2,3,4]
 => [1, 2, 3, 4]
2.6.5 :013 > arr.rotate
 => [2, 3, 4, 1]
2.6.5 :014 > arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
2.6.5 :015 > arr.rotate(2)
 => [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

For Ex :-

```
2.6.5 :021 > def array_rotation(array, shift = 1)
2.6.5 :022?>     array.rotate(- shift)
2.6.5 :023?>   end
 => :array_rotation
2.6.5 :024 > arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
2.6.5 :025 > array_rotation arr, 2
 => [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
2.6.5 :026 > arr = [1,2,3,4]
 => [1, 2, 3, 4]
2.6.5 :027 > array_rotation arr, 1
 => [4, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: In my opinion there is no reason to create a new method only to flip an integer from positive to negative. I would use `array.rotate(-n)` where `array` is the array and `n` is the number of elements to rotate backwards.

Comment: @3limin4t0r : Completely agree. Added a method just to satisfy the given conditions.

Comment: The question does not call for the creation of a method. In fact, the OP wants to use an existing method if there is one. Considering that you "completely agree" with @3limin4t0r I suggest you edit your answer and simply state that there is such a method: `Array#rotate`. There's no need to mention in an edit that it is an edit. If you wish to thank someone for a suggestion I suggest you do so in a comment, rather than in the answer, to keep the latter "clean".

Answer (score 1):

I believe you looking for [#rotate](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Array/rotate) method.

You can use it in something like this way

```rb
array.rotate(-shift)
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: `shift_rotate([1,2,3,4,5], 2)  #=> [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]`, not `[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]`. It would be simpler to write `array.rotate(-shift)`. In fact, why even create a method `shift_rotate` rather than just writing `array.rotate(-shift)`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm agree with you about `array.rotate(-shift)` but I'm not sure why you get different result then me from this method, may I ask you to share your Ruby version?

Comment: @CarySwoveland `shift_rotate([1,2,3,4,5], 2)  #=> [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]` in case if you will write: ` array.rotate(shift - array.size)` it's not the same as I did :)

Comment: My bad, or is it me bad? Strike the first sentence of my first comment.